# Sengrid Handlebars - How to shorten length of number in a custom field?

Tags: javascript, email, handlebars.js, sendgrid, handlebarshelper

I have a percentage field that's pulling through onto email as a 15 digit number (with 13 decimal places!) when i use this code: {{ insert average_delivery_frequency ‘default=My guess is as good as yours’ }}

**So I tried these but get an error message**:
• {{ insert round average_delivery_frequency ‘default=My guess is as good as yours’ }}
• {{ insert (round average_delivery_frequency) ‘default=My guess is as good as yours’ }}
• {{ round average_delivery_frequency }}

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

`width: 2ch !important; overflow: hidden;`

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question! SO kudos to you for persevering and for solving the issue on your own.  Please update your answer with an explanation of how you found the solution and why it works.